# How to "soft-limit" CPU usage of a process

Tags: limit, nice

I have some processes running on Debian that I want to limit cpu of it usage in the "soft" manner. For example, if it eats more than 70% of a single core for more than 15 minutes, the CPU should be limited to 30%. If it uses only 30-40% of a single core, it is free to run.

Currently, I have to manage it by logging into the server and do the work manually. Therefore, I am thinking to automate this tasks by some script/software and `crontab`. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cpulimit command`. It works like `nice`, but sets a limit instead of a niceness.

You did not say what OS you are using. On Debian (and derivatives) you can install with `apt install cpulimit`.

If is not good enough, then you will need process namespaces.